# Wrong Loop while and for

Tags: php

```
$arrayday=array();
$arrayTime=array();
$arrayTime1=array();
while($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7))
{
$arrayday[] = $row7['day'];
 $arrayTime[] =$row7['TimeIn'];
 $arrayTime1[] =$row7['TimeOut'];
}

for($a=0;$a<32;$a++)
{
    echo "<td>$a</td>";

    if($a==$arrayday[$a])
    {
        echo "<td>".$arrayTime[$a]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$arrayTime[$a]."</td>";
        echo "<tr>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td>No record</td>";
        echo "<td>No record</td>";
        echo "<tr>";    
    }
}
```

ok.. i got timein and timeout for day 20,27 and 28.. from this code, it will loop 3 time 1 to 30, for the 1st 1 to 30, it will put timein and timeout for day 20, not record for day 27 and 28. for the 2nd 1 to 30, it will put 20 and 27, and 3rd loop 1-30, it will put timein and timeout for 20,27 and 28.. i just need the 3rd loop.. which have 3 record in 1 to 30.

**This Problem Already Settle By @llya**

Comment: Apologies but bad english is not an excuse for an incomplete question. What is the intended output? What's it doing that you don't want? What is the input (`$result7`)? Are there any errors? :: I see you added some explanation in comments below. Please edit the original question to reflect what you need so future users can be helped as well. Thanks!

Comment: ok.. thanks~ i already edit the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
fixed for in while loop problem,
added forgotten /tr tag.

```
// collect list of days
$arrayday=array();
$arrayTime=array();
$arrayTime1=array();
while($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7)) {
  $arrayday[] = $row7['day'];
  $arrayTime[$row7['day']] =$row7['TimeIn'];
  $arrayTime1[$row7['day']] =$row7['TimeOut'];
}

// build table
for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
  echo "<td>$x</td>";
  if (in_array($x, $arrayday)) {
    echo "<td>".$arrayTime[$x]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$arrayTime1[$x]."</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";    
  } else {
    echo "<td>No record</td>";
    echo "<td>No record</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";    
  }
}
```

Comment: @llya also same, it will loop 1 to 30 3times.. $x will compare with $row7['day'], eg: x=1, $row7['day'] = 1, then out timein and timeout, then x will be 2, will compare with $row7['day'], if true the out timein and timeout, otherwise, no record.

Comment: ok.. i got timein and timeout for day 20,27 and 28.. from this code, it will loop 3 time 1 to 30, for the 1st 1 to 30, it will put timein and timeout for day 20, not record for day 27 and 28. for the 2nd 1 to 30, it will put 20 and 27, and 3rd loop 1-30, it will put timein and timeout for 20,27 and 28.. i just need the 3rd loop.. which have 3 record in 1 to 30.. :(

Comment: sorry, your code will update all timein and timeout based on the last day.. its should be different.. i just figure it out

Comment: i cant post picture here.. if you can give me your email, then i'll post in .docx what i want..

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand your problem. Please try my code (I changed it). I hope it is what you need.

Comment: yaaa..!!!! that's it.. Thank you so much..!! i cant vote.. its need 15 reputation.. <3